# Couldn't find Item with 'id'=; Destroy action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, destroy

I needed to customize my controllers so I did this:

routes:

```
post    'add_item', to: 'walls#create'
delete  'remove_item', to: 'walls#destroy'
```

destroy action WallsController:

```
def destroy
  @item = Item.find params[:id]
  @item.destroy
  redirect_to :back
end
```

view:

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
  <%= item.name %> <%= link_to "X", remove_item_path(item), method: :delete %>
<% end %>
```

Create action works just fine but still getting error with destroy action: `Couldn't find Item with 'id'=`

Many thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

remove_item_path is expecting an item id as argument.

```
link_to "X", remove_item_path(item.id), method: :delete
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
link_to "X", remove_item_path(id: item.id), method: :delete
```